# If momentum eigenstates are not in $L^2$, how can they form a basis for it?

Tags: operators, momentum, hilbert-space

When your matrices are all finite, the eigenvectors of a self-adjoint matrix $\mathbf{A}$ form an orthogonal basis for some space. It's almost too trivial to mention that each basis vector is, indeed, inside of the space that it is part of  a basis for.

The momentum operator $\mathbf{\hat p}$ is self-adjoint, and also has a spanning basis of eigenfunctions that span Hilbert space. However, *none* of the eigenfunctions of $\mathbf{\hat p}$ are square-integrable. What's going on?

Comment: Yes, but $p\neq L^2$...

Comment: A couple of articles about this:
[Wikipedia article about rigged Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space), [Paper about the role of rigged Hilbert spaces in Quantum Mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0502053).

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210300/how-to-make-rigorous-the-idea-of-a-continuous-complete-set#comment450025_210300) comment from Qmechanic may be helpful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The momentum operator $-i\hbar \nabla$ is indeed an unbounded self-adjoint operator on the hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, with domain $H^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, but it has **purely continuous spectrum**.

Operators with purely continuous spectra do not possess any eigenvector belonging to the hilbert space, and thus of course they *do not* possess a basis of eigenvectors. This is one of the differences between finite and infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

In the infinite dimensional case, only operators that are either compact (like density matrices) or with compact "inverse" (resolvent, more precisely, like the harmonic oscillator) have a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: If momentum eigenstates are not in  L2 , how can they form a basis for it?