# Divergence of probabilities for a position eigenstate in an energy basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

If we have an electron in a one-dimensional infinite potential well, and we have measured its position and found it to be let's say at $x=0$ at the center of the well. The state vector after measurement becomes $\ket\{x=0\}.$ If we calculate the probability then to get any eigen-value of the energy we will find it to be $\frac{1}{a}$ where $a$ is the width of the well. But that means the total probability (the sum of infinite terms each equals $\frac{1}{a}$) is infinite which is absurd. So, what exactly is happening here please?

Comment: The lab you've described has a position detector with infinite precision. Those sound nice - where did you find it? I'd like to get one for mine. (Joking aside: as you've just proved, position eigenstates are not physical, and cannot be achieved in real experiments.)

Comment: I liked the joke friend, but the problem persists. From totally mathematical point of view, this kind of result shouldn't occur if the axioms of QM represent a consistent mathematical theory.

Comment: @Arthur QM isn't pure math. You are starting with something that is not physical, so anything after this doesn't matter. The purpose of QM is to describe the physical world, not to cover all possible mathematical possibilities.

Comment: @Arthur Your state $|x=0\rangle$ is not normalized. Normalized states have unit probability. But unnormalized states don't have unit probability. There's no mathematical theory that says that an unnormalized states have probability add to one. The ONLY rigorous mathematical statement is that normalized states will have probabilities that add to one.

Comment: @AaronStevens As I see it, nothing in the axioms of QM says that position eigenstates are non-physical. Granted the axioms are telling us that position and momentum cannot be measured simultaneously, but that means if we have definite position, then in such a case momentum has no meaning, and vice versa. This is why I see it such a big conceptual problem if we get such a nonsensical result as infinite probability.

Comment: @JahanClaes this is exactly the problem I am talking about: since <x|x'>=delta(x-x'), this will always give us such a result.
But if we use the rules of QM, nothing wrong in writing for the probability to get the Nth eigenstate of energy:
P(n)=<x|n><n|x>
And when we sum over all the possible values of n we get:
sigma P(n) = <x|x>
which is infinite. This shouldn't happen!

Comment: @Arthur $\langle x|n\rangle\langle n|x\rangle$ is NOT a probability, so you writing is at $P(n)$ is simply incorrect. The postulates of quantum mechanics say that *for a normalized state* you have $P(n)=\langle \psi|n\rangle\langle n|\psi\rangle$. If your state $|\psi\rangle$ is not normalized, then the formula you've written is meaningless. The formula for "probability" REQUIRES you to first normalize your state.

Comment: @Arthur Some authors will write $P(n)=\frac{|\langle n|\psi\rangle|^2}{\langle\psi|\psi\rangle}$, and then this formula holds for any state whether or not it's normalized. Of course, if you try to put in $|\psi\rangle=|x\rangle$, you'll simply get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, which is a little hard to interpret. But at least then you can see directly why considering $|\psi\rangle=|x\rangle$ is problematic for QM, and why we never consider a particle to actually be in the state $|x\rangle$.

Comment: @JahanClaes your last two comments are really insightful. But is there a way to circumnavigate this situation?

Comment: @Arthur You cannot normalize the position eigenstate. It is not a normalizable function. That is precisely why you can never have a particle in a position eigenstate. Actual, physical wavefunctions are always normalizable. The position eigenstates are useful for EXPANDING physical wavefunctions and doing FORMAL MANIPULATIONS, but are not physical states a particle can be in.

Comment: @JahanClaes great help buddy, Thank you so much. I am new here and I am trying to give you a thumps up but I don't know how.

Comment: @Arthur I will consider this comment sufficient thumbs-up

Answer (score 2):

When the distribution of probabilities is continuous, the probability of finding an object exactly at one specific position is zero. You can calculate what is the probability of finding the object at a certain interval, you have a probability density. The right way to treat the probability is $dP(x)=dx/a$, and the total probability now becomes 1, because $\int dP(x)=\int^a_0 dx/a=1$. For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box

Comment: But the spectrum of energy is discrete, and it is this spectrum that I am trying to calculate the total probability for. The problem is that the individual probabilities are the same and are all 1/a.

Comment: The spectrum of the energy operator is discrete, but the spectrum of the position operator is continuum. An eigenstate of energy is not an eigenstate of position, the operators do not commute

Comment: you are correct in that a continuum spectrum is incompatible with a Hilbert space, that is why there are extensions to deal with this, although in practice this is almost never mentioned. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210300/how-to-make-rigorous-the-idea-of-a-continuous-complete-set

Comment: The fact that one observable has a continuous spectrum and the other doesn't, shouldn't cause problems if the axioms of quantum mechanics are true.
I appreciate it if you know how they deal with such a problem my friend.

Comment: Well, that is the problem, the formalism is incomplete if you want to use continumm spectrum operators. There is a whole bunch of literature to deal with it in a rigurous way, but that is complex and there is a lot of literarture on the web. In practice we just use probabilty densities and assume that everything works well

Comment: @Arthur You are essentially trying to write out a Dirac delta function as a Fourier series. Right?

Comment: @AaronStevens yes, you treat the eigenstates of position as a delta fuction. But remember that this is a generalized function, not a standard one. So it is really outside Hilbert space

Comment: Yes I completely agree. I just wanted to make sure we were all on the same page.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny may you please give me some materials which solve this particular problem if you have any?

Comment: @AaronStevens yes I am my friend.

Comment: @Arthur, I already posted  two links where you can start